# playframework: how to redirect to a post call inside controller action method

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I have some route define as:

```
Post /login  controllers.MyController.someMethod()
```

and inside `someMethod` I use `DynamicForm` to extract parameters from the post request.

works fine from browser or any client using Post method.

But if I need to call this url inside some action method (lets say `someAnotherMethod`) and want to pass some parameters also, how can I achieve this? What I mean is:

```
public static Result someAnotherMethod() {
// want to put some data in post request body and
return redirect(routes.MyController.someMethod().url());
```

Comment: Methods in play Controllers are static, why just can't you call them? From `someAnotherMethod` call `controllers.MyController.someMethod()` with the correct parameters

Comment: You did not get my point, Inside action methods when we want to call or redirect to another action method we normally use `return redirect(routes.MyController.someMethod().url())` but how can I pass parameters in this case (Do not forget this is a Post call and I am using `DynamicForm` to extract parameters inside `MyController.someMethod()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 1. With argument (it's not a redirect!)

You can return `Result` from other method without redirecting:

```
public static Result someMethod(){
    DynamicForm dynamicForm = form().bindFromRequest();
    return otherMethod(dynamicForm);
}

public static Result otherMethod(DynamicForm dataFromPrevRequest) {
    String someField = dataFromPrevRequest.get("some_field");
    Logger.info("field from request is: " + someField);
    return ok("Other method's Result");
}
```

#### 2. With cache (probably best replacement of POST data in these solutions)

Also you can store data from incoming request to the database or even 'cheaper' to the [Cache](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaCache) and then fetch it in other method.:

```
public static Result someMethod(){
    DynamicForm dynamicForm = form().bindFromRequest();

    Cache.set("df.from.original.request", dynamicForm, 60);
    return redirect(routes.Application.otherMethod());
}

public static Result otherMethod() {
    DynamicForm previousData = (DynamicForm) Cache.get("df.from.original.request");

    if (previousData == null) {
        return badRequest("No data received from previous request...");
    }

    // Use the data somehow...
    String someData = previousData.get("someField");

    // Clear cache entry, by setting null for 0 seconds
    Cache.set("df.from.original.request", null, 0);

    return ok("Previous field value was " + someData);
}
```

#### 3. As common GET

Finally you can just create method with required args only and pass them in the first method (receiving request).

```
public static Result someMethod(){
    DynamicForm df = form().bindFromRequest();

    return redirect(routes.Application.otherMethod(df.get("action"), df.get("id")));
}

public static Result otherMethod(String action, Long id) {
    return ok("The ID for " + action +" action was" + id);
}
```

Comment: In this case should I alter my route to something like: `Post /login  controllers.MyController.someMethod(data:DynamicForm)` ? If so, then this is not going to solve my problem. What I want is to not include any argument in the action method and get all parameters, which are variable in number(may be 2, 3 or etc) in my case, from the `DynamicForm`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I read the reference thread, But one more thing how will I pass arguments when calling this method from any other action method? for example If I call something like this `return redirect(myForm)` where myForm is an instance of Form class, will it work ?

Comment: It's not working in the case `return redirect(routes.MyController.someMethod(myForm))`, where myForm is an instance of Form class. :(

Comment: Please see my changes in the question, it'll be more clear to you now what I want to achieve.

Comment: @gmuhammad check the samples I added, most probably second will be best for you.

Comment: Thanks for continuous help. The second option is better, and since I also did not find any other better solution till now, I am accepting it as a solution to my problem. Thanks again.