# Play framework redirect post call

Tags: java, scala, playframework

So I just want to redirect some of my routes locally:

```
GET         /api/*url         # remove "/api/ and redirect GET url
POST        /api/*url         # remove "/api/ and redirect POST url
GET         /*url             com.example.Application.assetOrDefault(url)
GET         /                 com.example.Application.index()
```

so far I have tried to write a controller and use redirect method from within but that only works for GET calls. I don't have any language preference, Java or Scala both work fine.

Comment: @Wildahmmer, are you asking for help getting a redirect working for a POST, and can you show you controller code?

Comment: Yes. Controller is just a simple redirect(url)

Comment: Might [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068523/playframework-how-to-redirect-to-a-post-call-inside-controller-action-method) be of help?